# create javascript object (with key pairs) from json (not in correct key pair)

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I don't know how to extract key/values from a json array to hook them into different parts of a javascript array.

E.g. I have 2 json arrays which looks like this:

series 1:

```
{"label1":"91970","label2":"1231", ...  "labeln": "somenumbers".}
```

series 2:

```
{"label1":"4556","label2":"3434", ....}
```

I would like to transform both of them to 1 javascript object (for nvd3 plotting) like this:

```
long_short_data = [ 
  {
    key: 'Series1',
    color: '#d62728',
    values: [
      { 
        "cell" : "label1" ,
        "value" : 91970
      } , 
      { 
        "cell" : "label2" ,
        "value" : 1231
      } ,
.....
    ]
  },
  {
    key: 'Series2',
    color: '#1f77b4',
    values: [
      { 
        "cell" : "label1" ,
        "value" : 4556
      } , 
      { 
        "cell" : "label2" ,
        "value" : 3434
      } , 
 ...
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could consider using [d3.keys](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_keys), for example:

```
var series1 = {"label1":"91970","label2":"1231","labeln": "453453"};
var series2 = {"label1":"4556","label2":"3434"};
var long_short_data = [ 
  {
    key: 'Series1',
    color: '#d62728',
    values: []
  },
  {
    key: 'Series2',
    color: '#1f77b4',
    values: []
  }
];
d3.keys(series1).forEach(function(d) { 
    long_short_data[0].values.push(
      { 
        "cell" : d ,
        "value" : +series1[d]
      }
    );
});
d3.keys(series2).forEach(function(d) { 
    long_short_data[1].values.push(
      { 
        "cell" : d ,
        "value" : +series2[d]
      }
    );
});
```

`long_short_data` will be created, as defined in your question

Comment: Thanks, that's a great solution. I'm a noob and so unfortunately can't give you an upvote according to the system.

Comment: Glad it helped.  You can't upvote, but you should be able to accept the answer. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from hollow to green

Comment: I just did. Thanks again. Sorry it took do long.

Answer (score 0):

Given a JSON string, you should first call `JSON.parse()` to convert it into a Javascript object.

You can then use the function `Object.keys(obj)` which returns an array of properties that belong directly to `obj` to build your array:

```
var array = [];
for (var ii = 0, keys = Object.keys(series); ii < keys.length; ii++) {
    array.push({ cell : keys[ii], value : series[keys[ii]] });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful for my understanding.  On further thought, I think I should clean up php data first i.e. the array/hash setup on the php/server side before working on js/client level i.e. get the php hash configured completely (merge both series there) and then when I do a json_encode on it, it'll be the correct json before calling json_parse to get the object.